# Configuração Jest + Mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, jest

Estou estudando jest e travei em uma parte no curso onde é feita a configuração do projeto para rodar o `jest` junto ao `mongodb`.

Estou utilizando a dependência [@shelf/jest-mongodb](https://github.com/shelfio/jest-mongodb).

jest-mongodb-config.js

```
module.exports = {
  mongodbMemoryServerOptions: {
    binary: {
      version: '4.0.3',
      skipMD5: true
    },
    instance: {
      dbName: 'jest'
    },
    autoStart: false
  }
}
```

jest-config.js

```
module.exports = {
  roots: ['<rootDir>/src'],
  collectCoverageFrom: ['<rootDir>/src/**/*.ts'],
  coverageDirectory: 'coverage',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  preset: '@shelf/jest-mongodb',
  transform: {
    '.+\\.ts$': 'ts-jest'
  }
}
```

mongo-helper.ts

```
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb'

export const MongoHelper = {
  client: null as MongoClient,

  async connect (uri: string): Promise<void> {
    this.client = await MongoClient.connect(uri, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true
    })
  },

  async disconnect (): Promise<void> {
    await this.client.close()
  }
}
```

trecho do arquivo account.spec.ts que faz a conexão

```
  beforeAll(async () => {
    await MongoHelper.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL)
  })

  afterAll(async () => {
    await MongoHelper.disconnect()
  })
```

Porém ao rodar o teste, estou recebendo o erro:

```
Determining test suites to run...Starting the instance failed, please enable debug for more infomation


  ● Test suite failed to run

    Status Code is 403 (MongoDB's 404)
    This means that the requested version-platform combination doesn't exist

      at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (node_modules/mongodb-memory-server-core/lib/util/MongoBinaryDownload.js:378:44)
```

Tentei algo que vi em alguns posts para incluir no meu package.json o trecho abaixo, mas o resultado é o mesmo.

```
"config": {
  "mongodbMemoryServer": {
    "version": "latest"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, também estava com o mesmo problema. "latest" também não funcionou pra mim.

Utilize ao invés de "latest" o número da versão atual:

```
"config": {
  "mongodbMemoryServer": {
    "version": "4.4.1"
  }
}
```

Para mais dúvidas https://github.com/nodkz/mongodb-memory-server/issues/316

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, tentei mas o resultado foi o mesmo. `Status Code is 403 (MongoDB's 404)`

Comment: Ao executar o teste, ele deveria ter criado um arquivo na raiz, chamado "globalConfig.json", com uma propriedade "mongoUri" que aponta para o banco em memória. Verifique se ele criou o arquivo. Se não criou, tente adicionar a propriedade "config" com outra versão do banco e aplique ela com yarn ou npm install.